# Complexity of these two nested for loops

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

What is the complexity of these nested for loops:

```
for(int p=2; p<=LENGTH; p++){
    for(int i=1; i*p <= LENGTH; i++)
    {
           //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: O(LENGTH^2) would think.